# Change the theme of a datepicker

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I want to have a datepicker that looks something like this

[image]

But i get something like this

[image]

Anyone that got a good example of a theme to use ?

Comment: The datepicker view you get is default for lollipop devices, AFAIK I cannot be changed like older one

Comment: Ohh, soo i cant get the nice style like in older version of android? thats kinda bad :(

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to develop custom date picker. May be it would help you.

https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker